# Custom JS aggregation function reactable groups pull data from table

Tags: javascript, r, reactable

I have a dataset of groups that looks something like this:

```
1   Groupname

11  Subgroupname
111 Subsubgroupname1
112 Subsubgroupname2

12  Subgroupname
121 Subsubgroupname
122 Subsubgroupname


2   Groupname

21  Subgroupname
211 Subsubgroupname1
212 Subsubgroupname2

22  Subgroupname
221 Subsubgroupname
222 Subsubgroupname
```

Ideally, I'd like to use reactable with groupBy so that at first, only the large groups with a single digit (which range from 1 to 9) are shown, but when you expand it, you see the two-digit subgroups, and then you can expand each of the subgroups to show the "subsubgroups" with three digits.

I've tried using the nested table function / details option out of reactable but the columns/contents aren't aligned as nicely as I would want (https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#nested-tables-1)

However, when I use the groupBy option (https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#grouping-and-aggregation-1)
the names of the Groups and Subgroups are not shown in the expandable row as I would expect. I believe I have to specify a custom aggregate function through JS but I don't really need to aggregate anything – my date is already aggregated if you will, I just want a specific way to show it.

Here's my code so far (and a link to the data file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yisn36ekchyeogs/cno11_estructura.xls?dl=0)

```
rm(list = ls())

library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(reactable)

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))  # Set working directory 


#Reads data, cleans it ----
ocup  <- readxl::read_excel("cno11_estructura.xls",
                                 col_names = F,
                                 sheet     = 1,
                                 range     = "A1:B761")

colnames(ocup) <- c("codigo_ocup", "nombre_ocup")

cod1d <- as.character(0:9)
            
ocup <- ocup %>%
          filter(nchar(codigo_ocup) != 1 | codigo_ocup %in% cod1d) %>%
          filter(nchar(codigo_ocup) <  4) %>%
          mutate(digitos = case_when(nchar(codigo_ocup) == 1 ~ 1,
                                     nchar(codigo_ocup) == 2 ~ 2,
                                     nchar(codigo_ocup) == 3 ~ 3)
                 )

ocup1d <- ocup[ocup$digitos==1,c("codigo_ocup", "nombre_ocup")]
ocup2d <- ocup[ocup$digitos==2,c("codigo_ocup", "nombre_ocup")]
ocup3d <- ocup[ocup$digitos==3,c("codigo_ocup", "nombre_ocup")]

# Attempt using nested tables works but columns are not nicely aligned 
reactable(ocup1d, details = function(index) {
  ocup2d_temp <- ocup2d[substr(ocup2d$codigo_ocup,1,1) == ocup1d$codigo_ocup[index], ]
  htmltools::div(style = "padding: 16px",
                 reactable(ocup2d_temp, details = function(index) {
                   ocup3d_temp <- ocup3d[substr(ocup3d$codigo_ocup,1,2) == ocup2d$codigo_ocup[index], ]
                   htmltools::div(style = "padding: 16px",
                                  reactable(ocup3d_temp, outlined = F)
                   )
                 })
  )
})


#Attempt using groupBy does not show "title" of the group properly
ocup$digitos <- NULL
ocup$codigo_ocup_1d <- substr(ocup$codigo_ocup,1,1)
ocup$codigo_ocup_2d <- substr(ocup$codigo_ocup,1,2)

reactable(ocup,
          groupBy = c("codigo_ocup_1d", "codigo_ocup_2d")
          )
```

Any chance I can get the proper expanding behavior of the nested tables, and the proper column alignment of the groupBy option? Many thanks in advance!